# Mutate each column with function with two parameter grouped by another column

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, tidyr, tidyverse

Following dataset represents my situations:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(
  G1 = rep(1:2, each = 10),
  G2 = rep(1:10, 2),
  C1 = rnorm(20),
  C2 = rnorm(20),
  C3 = rnorm(20),
  C4 = rnorm(20)
)
```

I want to perform following operation,

```
df %>%
  group_by(G1, G2) %>%
  mutate(
    C1 = C1 - C2,
    C2 = C2 - C2,
    C3 = C3 - C2,
    C4 = C4 - C2
  )
```

If there are only 4 columns (C1, C2, C3 and C4), I can apply above solution. However, I have many columns and for each of them, I need to do the same operation. Is there any concise and simple solution that could extend this problem to many columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can find some commonality in the column names you wish to mutate you can take advantage of `dplyr::mutate_at()` :

```
df %>%
    group_by(G1, G2) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with("C")), funs(. - C2))
```

### Edit

Because `mutate()` operates and stores the result for each column sequentially you have two options to get around the problem. You could use `reorder(df, everything(), C2)` so your `C2` is the last in your `data.frame` or add a second line like this:

```
set.seed(1)
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(
    G1 = rep(1:2, each = 10),
    G2 = rep(1:10, 2),
    C1 = rnorm(20, 0),
    C2 = rnorm(20, 1),
    C3 = rnorm(20, 10),
    C4 = rnorm(20, 100)
)


df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with("C"), -C2), funs(. - C2)) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(C2), funs(. - C2))
```

This just does the mutate for every column except `C2` on the first line. Then the second line goes back and mutates `C2` after the other columns are happily subtracted.

Comment: Very nice answer, In my original situation, I don't have columns starts with "C" in that situation, how can I select all the variables except grouping variables?

Comment: you can adjust to `vars(-G1, -G2)`

Comment: Ok, so in this case I don't even need to do grouping. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, to say, but this is not working.. When I use (. - C2), C3 and C4 will actually subtracting from 0 which is C2 - C2. Please, help me out with alternative solution.

Comment: @TheRimalaya let me know if my edit gets it back to working

Answer (score 2):

How about using `data.table` specifying the columns you want with `.SDcols`?

```
library(data.table)
cols <- colnames(df)[which(grepl("C",colnames(df)))]
dt <- setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x - C2), by=.(G1,G2), .SDcols = cols]
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I have already done it with data.table.